# Selenium - Test freezes and no TimeoutException when element not found

Tags: java, selenium

```
    public boolean isElementPresent(final By locator, long seconds) {
    Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(seconds))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        Logger.warning("Element '" + locator + "' is not present");
        return false;
    }
}
```

using function below with such code:

```
isElementPresent(someButton, 2)
```

when there is no needed element of page then test freezes for about 40 seconds but should throw TimeOutException after 2 seconds as we set.
Test freezes on following line:

```
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Could anyone help? It was OK before update selenium to 3.11.0

Comment: Can you help me to understand what exactly you are trying to do within `isElementPresent()` function?

Comment: In this case I'm checking if element is present on current page. It's OK when it's present but if not - test freezes for a long time (not the time I have set in the function)

Comment: What do you want to do if the element is present?

Comment: Sometimes I want to click or something else. It does not matter in this case.

Comment: Testcases and testscripts are written with respect to distinct teststeps. Teststeps can't be genalized for multiple test conditions.

Comment: @DenisRyabykh What was the version used before?

Comment: @Grasshopper 3.7.1